# tensorflow training is slow, stops running on gpu?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I'm running the cifar_train program from tensorflow's [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/). The tutorial says it reaches a peak performance of 86% after a few hours. I tried running this on my laptop, and after about 4 days it was still training. I'm wondering if I'm misreading the tutorial by thinking that it'll be finished after a few hours, or if that's the accuracy at that time. Also I'm looking at my gpu usage via afterburner and when I started it, it was around 30-40% usage, but after looking at it overnight the gpu usage is 0 and the cpu is at 100%. Is this normal?

Comment: So after thinking about it I think what is happening is after the few hours the model has reached a "peak" accuracy, in that continued training won't help much, however it'll continue to run the 100,000 steps. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes it will keep running for all iterations. You could either check what your accuracy is (see if its ~86%) or plot accuracy vs iterations and see whether the graph plateaus at some point